# How do I list newest directory and add as variable to bash script to process files recursively

Tags: bash

How do I list newest directory and add as variable to bash script to process files recursively

```
ls -t1 | head -n1
```

Works perfectly to list the latest directory, but I want to add that directory name to my script so I can process the files within using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls | while read -r FILE
do
    mv -v "$FILE" `echo $FILE | tr ' ' '_' `
done
ls | while read -r FILE
do
    mv -v "$FILE" `echo $FILE | tr '\*.JPEG' '\*.jpg' `
done
    mogrify -resize 750 *.jpg
wait 
    jpegoptim *.jpg –max=70 --strip-all
exit
```

I also want to process the files recursively, there might be at most one level of sub directories.

Basically keep the bash script at the root of the directory and process all latest directories and sub directories files.

OK I modified the script to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR=ls -t1 | head -n1
ls $DIR | while read -r FILE
do
    mv -v "$FILE" `echo $FILE | tr ' ' '_' `
done
ls $DIR | while read -r FILE
do
    mv -v "$FILE" `echo $FILE | tr '\*.JPEG' '\*.jpg' `
done
    mogrify -resize 750 $DIR/*.jpg
wait 
    jpegoptim $DIR/*.jpg –max=70 --strip-all
exit
```

But it does not seem to recognise the $DIR variable.

Comment: Shouldn't `DIR=ls -t1 | head -n1` be replaced by `DIR=$(ls -t1 | head -n1)`?

Comment: @sgibb tried that but get same result = no result

Comment: does your operation `ls -t1 | head -n1` (without anything about DIR involved), produce the result you expect? I'm not used to the `head -n1` syntax, is that blowing it up? Good luck.

Comment: @sgibb You are right, the `$()` is needed (and I checked it does work for me). Maybe OP's machine has an incompatible version of `head`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bash script will rename and convert the jpg files in the newest directory in the current directory and the files in the first level of directories under that directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

FIRST_DIR=`ls -t1F | grep / | head -n1`
DIR="./${FIRST_DIR}"
ls -t1F $DIR | while read -r FILE
do
    if [ "$FILE" ]
    then
        if [[ $FILE = */ ]]
        then
            echo "here ${DIR}${FILE}."
            DEEP_DIR="${DIR}${FILE}"
            ls -t1 $DEEP_DIR | while read -r FILE2
            do
                if [ "$FILE2" ]
                then
                    if [[ $FILE2 != */ ]]
                    then
                        RENAME=`echo ${FILE2//\*/} | tr ' ' '_' `
                        mv -v "${DEEP_DIR}${FILE2//\*/}" "${DEEP_DIR}${RENAME}"
                        FILE2=$RENAME

                        RENAME2=`echo ${FILE2//\*/} | tr '\*.JPEG' '\*.jpg' `
                        mv -v "${DEEP_DIR}${FILE2//\*/}" "${DEEP_DIR}${RENAME2}"
                        FILE2=$RENAME2
                    fi
                fi
            done

            mogrify -resize 750 "$DEEP_DIR*.jpg"
            wait 
            jpegoptim "$DEEP_DIR*.jpg" –max=70 --strip-all
        fi
        if [[ $FILE != */ ]]
        then
            RENAME=`echo ${FILE//\*/} | tr ' ' '_' `
            mv -v "${DIR}${FILE//\*/}" "${DIR}${RENAME}"
            FILE=$RENAME

            RENAME2=`echo ${FILE//\*/} | tr '\*.JPEG' '\*.jpg' `
            mv -v "${DIR}${FILE//\*/}" "${DIR}${RENAME2}"
            FILE=$RENAME2   
        fi
    fi
done
if [ "$FIRST_DIR" ]
then
    mogrify -resize 750 "$DIR*.jpg"
    wait 
    jpegoptim "$DIR*.jpg" –max=70 --strip-all
fi
```

Here are a couple of good links about bash programming:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Comment: Thanks Eric for this I tried the script but I get lots of errors: ls: cannot access 3: No such file or directory: line 15: [: too many arguments - line 7: [: too many arguments. Basically nothing happens.

Comment: Which OS are you running this on? @Grant

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10 but will ultimately run on CentOS @Eric

Comment: The problem is the l on ls -lt1F Just remove it and everything will work. so that the 3rd line ls should be ls -t1F @Grant

Comment: Tried that and get the following: here ./20120315-week_10_2012_/brun/.
./bash2.sh: line 15: [: too many arguments
./bash2.sh: line 15: [: too many arguments

Comment: Change line 15 to if [ "$FILE2" ] and line 46 to if [ "$FIRST_DIR" ] @Grant

Comment: OK partial success, the sub/sub dir files have all been renamed without spaces and _ added, but the sub dir remains unchanged. I get the following errors now:  mv: cannot stat `./20120315-week_10_2012_/New Members 9 March 2012 072.JPG*': No such file or directory. "20120315-week_10_2012_" is the newest dir and "/20120315-week_10_2012_/brun/" is the sub dir within, all the files in brun are sorted.

Comment: where is the file 'New Members 9 March 2012 072.JPG' located? @Grant

Comment: Within the newest dir it looks like this: 20120315-week_10_2012_/New Members 9 March 2012 027.JPG. So basically one dir down from the bash script. The dir within 20120315-week_10_2012_/ called "brun" works fine all its contents are renamed and optimised by the bash script but not the contents of its parent 20120315-week_10_2012_

Comment: Check and make sure lines 37 and 41 have double quotes around the file names like so mv -v "${DIR}${FILE}" "${DIR}${RENAME2}".

Comment: Yeah they do: Line 37 mv -v "${DIR}${FILE}" "${DIR}${RENAME}" Line 41 mv -v "${DIR}${FILE}" "${DIR}${RENAME2}"

Comment: It's always better for /bin/mv scripts to use `echo /bin/mv ${DIR}/${FILE} ...`, as the final output, then REVIEW THE OUTPUT of same. When all is working as needed AND there are no new surprises in output, THEN redirect output for execution into a temp shell, i.e. `myFileRenamerScript targetFiles* | bash`. Good luck to all.

Comment: @Grant I found the problem that file is marked executable. So I changed the code above to remove the * added to the file name by the ls -F command. The -F is needed to get the / on directory names.

Comment: Great! Tx so much it works now. I notice the file names now have 2 ** after the .JPG

Comment: Actually everytime I run the bash script it adds a * to the file extension, I now got files like so: New_Members_9_March_2012_056.JPG*** Also the files wont rename to .jpg

Comment: PURE AWESOMENESS! Eric you are a star! Works perfectly. I have learnt a lot from your help, Thank You Very Much!